# Web server sample that supports web sockets in Nim

Tags: websocket, webserver, nim-lang

Does anybody know of a good sample project of a simple web server in Nim that also supports web sockets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a fairly basic package to do this: https://github.com/niv/websocket.nim.

I successfully used it in some JavaScript games already.

Comment: I saw that website, but didn't know if it worked because the website said it was a pre-release. But if you're using it, I'll try it. Thanks for your help.